# Canonicalizing XML in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, digital-signature, saml

I'm working on a SAML gateway using Ruby/Rails and I'm attempting to write some code that validates the [xml digital signature](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/08/xmldsig.html#verify) of the incoming SAML response against the x509 cert of the originating service.

My problem: the signature depends on a canonicalized version of the XML that is hashed and then signed and I'm having trouble finding a ruby lib/gem that will canonicalize XML per [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xml-exc-c14n-20020718/). I found a [super old gem on rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/projects/c14n-r/) that is a mess but I'd be more interested if something like nokogiri supported this kind of functionality (from the nokogiri docs, it doesn't).

I've googled extensively but thought I'd ask around here to see if anyone has any good insights before I go and try to write my own version or rework the existing c14n-r library.

Comment: There is a [xmldsig](https://github.com/benoist/xmldsig) gem to verify and sign XML documents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give these two gems a shot:

http://rubygems.org/gems/coupa-libxml-ruby

http://rubygems.org/gems/xmlsec-ruby

I wrote them for a SAML project. The first patches libxml-ruby to add a binding for the canonicalize function in the base C library.

The latter is ruby binding for xmlsec. Right now all that works is signature verification, which was all I needed for the project, but it sounds like it'd fit your needs too.

I'd recommend going with xmlsec because trying to write your own XML signature verification code is an exercise in futility. Just wait til you have to deal with multiple enveloped signatures, embedded certificates, gah. Let xmlsec handle that crap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip man; I'll give the xmlsec lib a try.  Unfortunately, nokogiri delayed c14n support until the 1.4.4 release but that was released recently and I don't see it there either.  It may have been pushed back again to 1.5.  In the meantime I'll give this a try!

Comment: Just for the record, Nokogiri has now support for canonicalize: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-canonicalize

Comment: libxml-ruby also integrated the canonicalize method. http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Document.html#method-i-canonicalize

Answer (score 1):

After looking around some more I've found that nokogiri has put c14n support on the todo list for the [next release](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues#issue/226).  Don't know more than that-- but it appears that no widely used XML library supports c14n as of June 2010.  I'll close this out since nothing really popped up.

Comment: The Nokogiri version I am using now (v1.6.5) definitely supports canonicalization. I use it like so: `Nokogiri::XML(xml_string) { |config| config.strict }.canonicalize`

Answer (score 0):

I have a ruby/rails Service Provider and a .NET (ComponentSoft) IDP

this worked for me ( I had no issues with the canonicalized version of the XML):

```
received_certificate = XPath.first(response_document,"//samlp:Response//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Data//X509Certificate").text

def self.verify_signature(received_certificate, idp_certificate_path)
  certificate ||= OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(idp_certificate_path))
  cert_decoded = Base64.decode64(received_certificate)
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(cert_decoded)
  certificate.verify(cert.public_key)
end
```

Comment: True-- I need to validate the signed <SignatureValue> content against the digested <SignedInfo> contents using the X509 cert.  The above code will validate that the X509 cert matches what it says it does, but unless you verify the <SignatureValue> then you don't know if the message originated from that cert.

Comment: I found few links that might help:
http://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/master/lib/xml_sec.rb
http://rubygems.org/gems/XMLCanonicalizer
http://rubygems.org/gems/saml2ruby

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late and not really ideal, but [this fork](https://github.com/carnesmedia/savon/commit/13f47e8bc3a0fe3edcf82b3bf6961888b3c303ab) uses XMLStarlet via command line for canonicalization.

Answer (score 0):

The xmlcanonicalizer gem seems to be the most up-to-date ruby canonicaliser available:

https://github.com/andrewferk/xmlcanonicalizer

It does have a bug however, that makes it useless at canonicalising some XML trees. Some kind person has submitted a patch but it hasn't been applied yet:

https://github.com/andrewferk/xmlcanonicalizer/pull/1

This patched gem plus ruby-saml does the trick (plus more, if you're trying to implement SAML SSO:

https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml

Hope that helps someone save the 3 days I wasted trying to get things to work! :)

Answer (score 0):

had problems with xmlcanonicalizer.

xmlstarlet worked for me:

```
`echo "#{xml_str}" | xmlstarlet c14n`
```